# Retrieve data from SQLite database and display to TextView

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I need to display data to `TextView` to other `Fragment` after login`onClick` but I'm getting `NullPointerException` when retrieving data from `SQLite` database

Here's my code:

```
public Cursor getUserData() {
    String[] userData = new String[] { SqlDbHelper.COL_CODE,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_FNAME, SqlDbHelper.COL_LNAME,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_ADDRESS, SqlDbHelper.COL_LOCATION,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_CONTACT };
    Cursor c = database.query(SqlDbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, userData, null,
            null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
         bundle.putString("Code",
         c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_CODE)));
         bundle.putString("Firstname",
         c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_FNAME)));
         bundle.putString("Lastname",
         c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_LNAME)));
         bundle.putString("Address",
         c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_ADDRESS)));
         bundle.putString("Location",
         c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_LOCATION)));
         bundle.putString("Contact",
         c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_CONTACT)));
    }
    return c;
}
```

onClick :

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            sharedPreferences();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login Successful", 20).show();

            Log.d("DocLogin", user.getText().toString());
            Log.d("LoginDetails", "username:" + user.getText());
            Log.d("LoginDetails", "password:" + pass.getText());
            Cursor cur = dbcon.getuser_information(user.getText()
                    .toString(), pass.getText().toString());
            if (cur.getCount() != 0) {

                Cursor cursor = dbcon.getDocData();
                if(cursor.getCount() !=0) {
                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DocProfile());
                    ft.commit();
                }
            } else {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity()).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Login Error");
                alertDialog
                        .setMessage("Doctor Code and Password does not match");
                alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // dismiss dialog
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }

        }
    });
```

and here's where I want to display the data using `TextView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_profile, container, false);


    dbcon = new SQLController(getActivity());
    dbcon.open();

    TextView fname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.doc_firstname);
    TextView lname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.doc_lastname);
    TextView add = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_address);
    TextView loc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_location);
    TextView con = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_contact);


    String firstname = "", lastname = "", address = "", location = "", contact = "";

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    firstname = bundle.getString("Firstname");
    lastname = bundle.getString("Lastname");
    address = bundle.getString("Address");
    location = bundle.getString("Location");
    contact = bundle.getString("Contact");

    fname.setText(firstname);
    lname.setText(lastname);
    add.setText(address);
    loc.setText(location);
    con.setText(contact);

    return view;
}
```

and it says that I'm getting `NullPointerException` at this codes

```
    firstname = bundle.getString("Firstname");
    lastname = bundle.getString("Lastname");
    address = bundle.getString("Address");
    location = bundle.getString("Location");
    contact = bundle.getString("Contact");
```

Comment: `bundle` must be `null` then. This means that you never call `setArguments()` on your fragment.

Comment: sorry but where should i call `setArguments()` ?

Comment: Perhaps in `getUserData()`. You create a `Bundle` there, but don't do anything with it.

Comment: It's very hard to understand your design because you only show us individual methods and not the classes that contain them.

Comment: Feel free to look at [this fragment class](https://github.com/BaseballCardTracker/bbct/blob/master/gradle/android/src/main/java/bbct/android/common/activity/BaseballCardDetails.java) for an example. Note that I have a POJO to hold the data which is displayed. I find this helpful in simplifying the code.

Comment: I'm new in programming I really don't understand some of your codes

Comment: I know it is pretty complex. That class has evolved over the last two years of developing my app. Feel free to ask specific questions if there is something you want clarified.

Comment: is there any simple code that can solve my problem

Comment: You already have 100+ lines of code. It's not going to get much simpler from there.